# Java pword-generator does not update random inside loop

Tags: java

Im working on an assignment for school where i am going to finish a short password generator.
when trying to loop adding characters out of the string, it ends up adding the same character, but if i would just print out characters it gives different ones. could someone explain why this is? i would really like to learn.

```
private void program() {
    
    System.out.println(generate(all));

    }

Random rand = new Random();

String all = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    int randomInt = rand.nextInt(all.length());
    char randomchar = all.charAt(randomInt);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String generate (String string) {

        while (sb.length() < 10) {
            sb.append(randomchar);
        }
        return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Well, you're appending the same character each time through the loop.  Maybe add one line inside the loop that calls the random generator each time?

Comment: oh, i thought initializing random int once meant it was always random. but yes this tip worked it out. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `nextInt` and `nextChar` gloabally. This need to be moved to your generation method.

```
String generate (String string) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       while (sb.length() < 10) {
           int randomInt = rand.nextInt(all.length());
           char randomchar = all.charAt(randomInt);
           sb.append(randomchar);
        }
        return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Nope, still broken.

Comment: That won't make any difference to the main problem ;)

Comment: I forgot to set the while ontop of the method - adjusted

Comment: thank you! it worked once i placed them inside the loop. i thought random was always random and didnt need to be re-initialized between each iteration.

Comment: @Muguwaranojar thats true for the main `Random` class instance which generates a random number/... but ofcause selecting values from it need to be done every time looped/from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Size your `StringBuilder` for efficiency (and big passwords)

```
public String generatePassword(String candidateChars, int passwordLength) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int max = candidateChars.length();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(passwordLength);

    for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
        char randomchar = candidateChars.charAt(rand.nextInt(max));

        sb.append(randomchar);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should (re-)generate `randomInt` as well as `randomchar` *within* loop:

```
while (sb.length() < 10) {
  // we want fresh value on each iteration  
  int randomInt = rand.nextInt(all.length());
  char randomchar = all.charAt(randomInt);

  sb.append(randomchar);
}
```